# yeoman generator-ember doesn't show anything in browser

Tags: ember.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Following this *https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember* tutorial to use EmberJS with Yeomane, after running `grunt server` the browser is blank.

I expected to see this page but nothing shows up:![enter image description here][1]

***UPDATE:***

console error:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/style.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember/ember.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ember-data-shim/ember-data.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ember is not defined compiled-templates.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ember is not defined combined-scripts.js:3
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/affix.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/alert.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/dropdown.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/tooltip.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/modal.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/transition.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/button.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/popover.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/carousel.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/scrollspy.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/collapse.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/tab.js
```

***Update 2:***

```
works-Mac:myemberapp1 work$ grunt server
Running "server" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "replace:app" (replace) task
Replace app/index.html -> .tmp/index.html

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "emberTemplates:dist" (emberTemplates) task
    File ".tmp/scripts/compiled-templates.js" created.

    Done, without errors.

    Running "compass:server" (compass) task

    Done, without errors.

Running "neuter:app" (neuter) task

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @kingpin2k re-updated.

Comment: Do you see any messages in the terminal window running grunt?

Comment: @SteveH. Just apdate it again with the terminal windows.

Comment: Did you do a `bower install` and `npm install` ?

Comment: @SteveH. I should? it was not mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: @SteveH. and how to install bower? `sudo npm install bower` or just: `bower install`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44024/discussion-between-steve-h-and-asme-just)

Comment: ho great, didn't know Stack this feature,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the scaffolding is complete, you must run the commands `bower install` and `npm install` to install the required packages (described in the `bower.json` and `package.json` files.  After this, grunt will be able to serve up the dependencies.

As you build up your project and use introduce new dependencies, you'll add them by editing your `bower.json` and/or `package.json` files and rerunning the installs.  Downloaded packages are usually not stored in source control.

Answer (score 4):

For the specific error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/styles/style.css`, you should also check that you have got the `compass` server installed. That is:

```
gem install compass
```

To check that compass is running correctly, run `grunt serve --verbose` and check the output for any errors, such as:

```
in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [...] (Gem::LoadError)
```